# SSH tunnel & Rsync thru two proxy/firewalls

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-tunnel

Screnario:

```
[internal_server_1]AA------AB[firewall_1]AC----+
          10.2.0.3-^        ^-10.2.0.2         |
                                            internet
          10.3.0.3-v        v-10.3.0.2         |
[internal_server_2]BA------BB[firewall_2]BC----+
```

Ports AC,BC has valid internet addresses. All systems run linux and have root acces to all.

Need securely rsync **internal_server_1:/some/path** into **internal_server_2:/another/path**

My idea is make ssh secure tunnel between two firewalls, e.g. from firewall_1

```
firewall1# ssh -N -p 22 -c 3des user2@firewall_2.example.com -L xxx/10.3.0.3/xxxx
```

and after will run rsync from internal_server_1 somewhat like:

```
intenal1# rsync -az /some/path user@xxxx.yyyy.com:/another/path
```

I don't know

- how to make a correct ssh tunnel for rsync (what ports need tunnel)
- and **to where** i will make the rsync? (remote comp address in case of ssh tunnel)

Any idea or pointer to helpfull internet resource for this case?

thanx.

Comment: Can you directrly connect from internal_server_1 to firewall_2? That would make things much more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the SSH port on firewall_2 ("BC" in your diagram) is accessible from the outside.  Can computers on network 1 (10.2.0.*) reach the internet directly (i.e. via NAT), or only by proxying via firewall_1?  Since you don't specify, I'll assume not.

Probably the simplest thing to do is to tunnel rsync over SSH tunneled over SSH (clearly, "simplest" is relative).  First, build the outer tunnel by running this on firewall_1:

```
firewall_1# ssh -N -p 22 -c 3des user2@firewall_2.example.com -L 10.2.0.2:5432:10.3.0.3:22
```

Note that this runs the local (firewall_1) end of the tunnel on bound to its internal IP (10.2.0.2), on an arbitrary port (I used 5432).

Then, from server_1, run rsync and use its `-e` option to run it over SSH:

```
server_1# rsync -e "ssh -N -p5432 -c 3des" -a /local/path server2user@10.2.0.2:/remote/path
```

This SSHes into port 5432 on the IP address 10.2.0.2, which the outer tunnel forwards to 10.3.0.3 (server_2) port 22 (standard SSH).

BTW, if coordinating the setup on multiple computers (i.e. creating a tunnel from firewall_1 and then using it from server_1) is difficult, let me know; with a bit more complexity, it's possible to fire it all off from server_1 with a single command.  Although you should be able to set up the outer tunnel once, and then just leave it up...

Answer (score 2):

SSH has an option called ProxyCommand which allows you to pass all SSH traffic to a command which can be run on a different host. Probably you can chain multiple of these together to achieve what you want to do.

If you can directly connect from internal_server_1 to firewall_2, you can use something like this (for example as value for `-e` if you're using rsync):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p firewall_2" internal_server_2
```

Comment: +1  Cannot thank you enough for pointing this out.  A quick google on `ProxyCommand` gave me [this page](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), which did exactly what I need to do.  Doing it manually with LocalForward, etc., was a painful mess.  This is a breeze, once I put things in `.ssh/config`, and made a few aliases.

Answer (score 0):

rsync uses SSH (port 22) by default. So, you need to do port-forwarding on your firewalls to be able to rsync from internal server 1 to internal server 2.

This can be done using `iptables` on firewall1 and firewall2 as follows:

**On firewall1**

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.0.3 -p tcp --dport 5022 -j SNAT --to-source AC.IP.addr.ess
```

**On firewall2**

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -s AC.IP.addr.ess -p tcp --dport 5022 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.3.0.3:22
```

Using such rules, you can access internal server2 from internal server1 using port 5022 like:

```
internal_server1$ ssh -p 5022 user@BC.public.ip.addr
```

Comment: This is just an example. You can choose another port/IP if you want.

Answer (score 0):

a tested complete command is like this:

```
rsync -av --delete -e "ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -l username -W %h:%p jumphost-ip'" ./source_path/ username@internal-ip:/dest_path/
```