# Rsync through secure head-node on storage cluster

Tags: firewall, rsync, cluster

I wish to use a specific head-node as contact address for my rsync backups, I do no wish to have the backend accessed directly, as it is not as hardened, nor as compatible with the rest of my environment. Also, I do not wish to change client configs when it changes.

I do not wish to store files on the head-node itself as its space is rather limited. Not concerned about the computational overhead of effectively doing two rsync transfers for each file, as the machines are powerful enough.

Example:

(LAN Computers) <--- files ---> Head Node <--- files ---> Storage Backend

Is there an easy way to do this? I have searched for a while but could not find any information about this.

Comment: More detail about the storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount your backend storage via NFS or something like that on the headnode. About every HPC cluster does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can tunnel SSH connections over other SSH connections to get what looks (to rsync anyway) like a connection from LAN computers to the backend. Unfortunately, this does require configuration on the client end. The simplest way to do this would be to add something like this to the ssh cofig file on the client:

```
Host storagebackend
    ProxyCommand ssh -e none user@headnode exec nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
```

(Note: this assumes netcat is installed as `nc` on the head node. If not, you'll need to install it or adjust the command.)

Then use rsync "directly" from the client to storagebackend. Note that you'll need to authenticate twice, first to the head node, then to the backend. If you're using public-key authentication, both private key files need to be on the client computer.

Making this more transparent on the client end may be tricky; can you expand on that need? I can think of a few tricks, like using a wrapper script around netcat on the head node, and having that automatically supply the "true" backend server name...

p.s. Here are some references on the subject: [a previous SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/379411/ssh-tunnel-rsync-thru-two-proxy-firewalls), [an article at CERN](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/ssh_tunneling.shtml), and [one with diagrams by Keith Herron](http://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh).